# Sha256 hash differs from machine to machine

Tags: c#, sha256

We have a process hashing images , and would like to be able to deploy the same process on other servers. How do I get the same Hash value for an image across different servers. Here is the code we u

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
byte[] imageBytes;

string imagePath = @"C:\Work\Projects\test.jpg";
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath);

using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

}

string photoCheckSumSha256 = ComputeSha256Checksum(imageBytes);
Console.WriteLine(photoCheckSumSha256);

 Console.ReadKey();

}



static string ComputeSha256Checksum(byte[] data)
{
using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
{
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256 sha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] sha256Ret = sha256.ComputeHash(stream);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < sha256Ret.Length; i++)
{
sb.Append(sha256Ret[i].ToString("x2"));
}

return sb.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: I think it's much more likely that it's the data which is changing than SHA256 results, e.g. due to different image encoding implementations. (Note that your code would be easier to read if you had `using` directives so you didn't need to fully-qualify all your type names...)

Comment: Have you double checked the `SHA256` hash with a tool shipped with your system (or a third party toolsuite)? As Jon pointed out, its more likely that your file contents have changed?

Comment: Try comparing the Hash for test.jpg with HashTab on both machines, just to be sure.  Oh and don't open the file that way, rather use `File.ReadAllBytes(path);` or something else, to avoid loading it into memory, and then converting it in memory again.

Comment: @JonSkeet is right. Different versions of Windows have different codecs installed that result in binary output.

Comment: Thaks for the input , would the image encoding change when a file is copied to another server ? Or does it factor in when we open the file programmatically? Any inputs on how to keep the encoding consistent when opening the file programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't even a guarantee that this will work the same way on the same machine from one run to another, as some implementations of JPEG encoding are non-deterministic.

Your algorithm so far is:

1. Get file.
2. Do arbitrary stuff with it that isn't actually used.
3. Store this in memory via a memory stream.
4. Take it out of memory via a memory stream.
5. Get hash of output of arbitrary stuff.

Your algorithm should be:

1. Get file.
2. Get hash of file.

You don't need to even care whether it is a JPEG file or not. The one possible advantage is that your code would throw an exception if .NET couldn't handle it as an image (a disadvantage in most cases, but an advantage if it's better to fail now than down the line). If that's necessary, you could call `Image.FromFile()` separately from the hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the image and saving to a memory stream, try streaming the file directly to the SHA256 provider:

```
/* using declarations:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
*/

static string ComputeFileChecksum(string filePath)
{
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        using (var sha256 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var hashBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(fileStream);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: handle non-existent file
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```